# Starting and then destroying a Foreground service won't stop VS debugger

Tags: android, xamarin, foreground-service

I have a foreground service which runs fine, when I close the application I use the OnDestroy method to stop my service. Everything seems to work but my debugger in VS2019 never stops. I checked the developer section in the emulator for Running services and there a none (related to this project), the application is closed.

This leads me to believe that there might still be something running in the back - or the VS is somehow bugged in this scenario. Am I doing the start and stop in a wrong way?

This is my service

```
[Service]
public class ForegroundService : Service
{
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.N)
        {
            StopForeground(StopForegroundFlags.Remove);
        }
        else
        {
            StopForeground(true);
        }
        StopSelf();

        base.OnDestroy();
    }

    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(
            Android.App.Application.Context,
            NotificationSettings.NotificationPendingIntentId,
            new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(MainActivity)),
            PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        var notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context, NotificationSettings.ChannelId)
            .SetContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .SetContentTitle(NotificationSettings.Notification_app_name)
            .SetContentText(NotificationSettings.Notification_text)
            .SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Android.App.Application.Context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.xamagonBlue))
            .SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.xamagonBlue)
            .SetDefaults((int)NotificationDefaults.Sound | (int)NotificationDefaults.Vibrate)
            .Build();

        StartForeground(NotificationSettings.SERVICE_RUNNING_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);

        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
}
```

This is inside MainActivity:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
    ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
    base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
    LoadApplication(new App());

    CreateNotificationChannel();

    startServiceIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ForegroundService));
    if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        StartForegroundService(intent);
    }
    else
    {
        StartService(intent);
    }
}

protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    StopService(startServiceIntent);

    base.OnDestroy();
}
```

**Update 1**

I think I'm on to something. If I `StopService(startServiceIntent);` on a button click and then close the app in emulator the debugger stops correctly. What I'm thinking is that OnDestroy is too late to call StopService, which leads to another question when should I then stop my service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and had to use this in my service class

```
public override void OnTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
{   
     if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
         StopForeground(true);
     else
         StopService(new Intent(this, typeof(YourServiceClass))); 
    base.OnTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
    //will kill threads when app is manually killed by user.
    Java.Lang.JavaSystem.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Marc thank you, this works. There's no need to use OnDestroy at all, OnTaskRemoved is sufficient.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you! OnDestroy will still be called if the user dismisses the notification without killing the app, so you can use it to free up resources if needed!